# MPNowPlayingInfoCenter not showing details

Tags: ios, swift

today I spent hours trying to figure out why `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter` is not working, but without success. I want it to show info in control center and lockscreen, the media is a video.

Here is the problem:

I have a singleton class called `GlobalAVPlayer` that holds an `AVPlayerViewController`. It is a singleton because there must be only one, and I need to access it globally.

```
class GlobalAVPlayer: NSObject {
static let sharedInstance = GlobalAVPlayer()

private var _currentVideo: Video?

var playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()

var isPlaying: Bool = false
var almostPlaying: Bool = false
var hasItemToPlay: Bool = false

var currentVideo: Video?
{
    set {
        _currentVideo = newValue
        notify_VideoChanged()
    }
    get {
        return _currentVideo
    }
}

private var player: AVPlayer!

override init()
{
    super.init()
    player = AVPlayer()
    playerViewController.player = player
    
    player.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "rate", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didPlayToEnd), name: "AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification", object: nil)
    
}

func itemToPlay(item: AVPlayerItem)
{
    if let player = player {
        almostPlaying = true
        hasItemToPlay = true
        player.replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem(item)
    }
}

func didPlayToEnd()
{
    print("[GlobalAVPlayer] End video notification")
    let time = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0, 1)
    player.seekToTime(time)
}
func play()
{
    if player.rate == 0
    {
        player.play()
        if player.rate != 0 && player.error == nil
        {
            isPlaying = true
            print("[GlobalAVPlayer] Playing video without errors")
        }
    }
}

func pause()
{
    if player.rate == 1
    {
        player.pause()
        if player.rate == 0 && player.error == nil
        {
            isPlaying = false
            print("[GlobalAVPlayer] Pausing video without errors")
        }
    }
}

func notify_PlaybackChanged()
{
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("globalAVPlayerPlaybackChanged", object: self)
}

func notify_VideoChanged()
{
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("globalAVPlayerVideoChanged", object: self)
}

override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    if keyPath == "rate" {
        let newRate = change!["new"] as! Int
        //rate = 0 (il player è fermo)      rate = 1 (il player sta andando)
        self.isPlaying = newRate == 1 ? true : false
        notify_PlaybackChanged()
    }
}

deinit
{
    player.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "rate", context: nil)
}
}
```

The init is called one time when app starts, after that I use "itemToPlay" method to change the video.
I have also correctly (I think) configured the audio session in AppDelegate:

```
do
    {
        let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        try session.setActive(true)
    }
    catch
    {
        print("[AppDelegate] Something went wrong")
    }
```

I tried to put `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.defaultCenter().nowPlayingInfo = something` everywhere, but at max I could see the video title in the control center for 1 second when I put it into the `play()` method. After that it disappeared and the playback controls went gray. Information is correctly stored, because when i print `nowPlayingInfo` content into the console everything is as expected.
I tried using `becomeFirstResponder` and `UIApplication.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents` in different places without success.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Starting with iOS 10 there is a `BOOL` property in `AVPlayerViewController` called **`updatesNowPlayingInfoCenter`**, that has the default value: `YES`. Just change it to `NO`:

```
//playerController is an instance of AVPlayerViewController
if ([self.playerController respondsToSelector:@selector(setUpdatesNowPlayingInfoCenter:)])
{
    self.playerController.updatesNowPlayingInfoCenter = NO;
}
```